# Simple text formatting, such as superscript, in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, format, superscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write superscript word for checkbox text in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925917/how-do-i-write-superscript-word-for-checkbox-text-in-java)

So I have this very simple program that basically consists of a GUI with a few text fields and a button.

The idea is that the user enters numbers into three fields and presses the button. Then what happens is a few mathematical procedures are carried out in the background, and the resuling answer is presented in a fourth text field.

Now, this does the job, but the formatting looks awful. At the very least, I would like to have part of the output superscripted. I have next to no experience with these things, but thought I would be able to get the hang of this on my own, but I'm stuck. I think I need to use AttributedString and possibly Font, but I can't get anything to work. And I've found no tutorials.

Does anyone have any quick pointers? That'd be most helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the output field to be editable? If not, try using a JLabel with HTML code. Something like:

```
jLabel4.setText("<html>ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c</html>");
```

You can add a border to that JLabel to make it look like a text field.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you yankitwizzy too! I had no idea JLabel handled HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use other swing components that support HTML to display the answer like JLabel. If you use a JLabel for instance you can use inline html to format your answer

Answer (score 0):

The reasons you are having difficulty has to do with the lack of a default typsetting system.  Font selection and such typically provides a very limited means to do proper math typesetting (which is a specialized subset of general typesetting).

I don't know of any math specific typesetting already built-in to the Java libraries, that said, perhaps you can [integrate the ExTex project](http://www.extex.org/index.html) into your Java components or roll your own solution using the 2d API (look at baseline offsetting).

Other alternatives are to generate a graphic, and display it's rendered image.  If the display is static, this might be a much easier choice.